# RESTful authentication in a hybrid web app

Tags: python, rest, authentication, flask

I'm writing an hybrid web app using flask. By hybrid I mean that there is the conventional web server application built with template engine and there is RESTful API for client side application as well. So here is my confusion:

In my current application, user logs in through the web server so that an HTTP session is created, the user then can do stuff. However, in one of the pages, there is a action that is done via AJAX call to the RESTful part of the same application. Normally in this API, the user will have to authenticate itself again. But here the client side code has no way of knowing the user name and password. What's the correct pattern here?

Comment: not necessarily authenticate him again, since you already did, and you have the cookie on the user browser, use it to check the session and perform the REST call!

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate the user client side in ajax call:

For example:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://example.com/api.ashx/v2/users.xml',
     beforeSend: addHeaders,
     dataType: "text",
     processData: false,
     success: function(data, status) {
          // do stuff here
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           // do stuff here
      }
 });

var addHeaders = function(xhr) {
     var restAuthHeader = readCookie("AuthorizationCookie");
     if (restAuthHeader != null) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Rest-Authorization-Code", restAuthHeader);
     }
 };

var readCookie = function(input) {
     var nameEQ = input + "=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[ i ];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
          if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
               return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
      }
      return null;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a form with username and password to authenticate.

```
<form id="login-form">
  <input data-key="username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
  <input data-key="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Your endpoint should return a token and a userid.

```
var $form = $('#login-form');
// post to your login endpoint with username and password
$.post('/login', {
  username: $form.find('input[data-key="username"]').val(),
  password: $form.find('input[data-key="password"]').val();
}).done(function (response) {
  // put the token and userid in the sessionStorage or localStorage
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('userId', response.data.userId);
}).fail(function (e) {
  // handle incorrect credentials here.
  alert('authentication failed');
});
```

You should append these to your headers to request data.

```
function requestEndpoint(endpoint) {
  $.ajax({
    // other stuff here you probably know
    headers: {
      'X-Auth-Token': window.sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
      'X-User-Id': window.sessionStorage.getItem('userId'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
}
```

Just scan for these headers at the endpoints in flask

Comment: Thanks for the input. It helps. But this implies a pure client side application relying entirely on Ajax calls. How would the conventional part work?

Comment: Are you using flask-login? If so, you can use the current_user on the server, and you can use the window.sessionStorage on the client for a more "hybrid" app